# How to place a Progress control within a WPF window like MozilaFirefox Browser

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, progress

I am developing a wpf application where I want to show a progress animation like how it is showing on MozilaFirefox something like below figure.

I tried with Statusbar control of WPF but again I want it should appear on the top of the window and disappear once processing done.

Please guide some example. Hints or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Processing]

Comment: I want something like floater kind of thing where I'll put my Busy indicator and once processing complete it will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a busy indicator.

There is one provided in the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/), here - http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator.

There is also one in the [Telerik suite of WPF controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx), here - http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/busyindicator.aspx.

Both can be customised to display your own content.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple busy indicator in XAML:

```
<Control Width="40">
    <Control.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="40" Height="40">
                                <Canvas.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                                        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </Canvas.Resources>
                                <Ellipse Width="21.835" Height="21.862" Canvas.Left="20.1696" Canvas.Top="9.76358" Opacity="1.0"/>
                                <Ellipse Width="20.835" Height="20.862" Canvas.Left="2.86816" Canvas.Top="29.9581" Opacity="0.9"/>
                                <Ellipse Width="19.835" Height="19.862" Canvas.Left="0.00001" Canvas.Top="57.9341" Opacity="0.8"/>
                                <Ellipse Width="17.835" Height="17.862" Canvas.Left="12.1203" Canvas.Top="83.3163" Opacity="0.7"/>
                                <Ellipse Width="16.835" Height="16.862" Canvas.Left="36.5459" Canvas.Top="98.1380" Opacity="0.6"/>
                                <Ellipse Width="14.835" Height="14.862" Canvas.Left="64.6723" Canvas.Top="96.8411" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                <Ellipse Width="13.835" Height="13.862" Canvas.Left="87.6176" Canvas.Top="81.2783" Opacity="0.4"/>
                                <Ellipse Width="12.835" Height="12.862" Canvas.Left="98.165"  Canvas.Top="54.4140" Opacity="0.3"/>
                                <Ellipse Width="11.835" Height="11.862" Canvas.Left="92.9838" Canvas.Top="26.9938" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinnerRotate" Angle="0"/>
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <Canvas.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentControl.Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SpinnerRotate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01.3" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Canvas.Triggers>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Control.Style>
</Control>
```

Comment: I have a customized busy indicator but want to use it at the bottom of the window like how Mozila fire fox browser using while loading a page.

Comment: So you have it already, but you just want to dock it to the bottom? In that case, use `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`. If you need to toggle visibility, you can simply bind it like so: `Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"`. (Remember to add `<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>` in resources)